# Formato DateTimePicker VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, date-format

El problema es el siguiente, mi DateTimePicker me devuelve un formato que no se corresponde con el que espera recibir la columna de la base de datos, por lo tanto dentro del código decidí darle un formato custom al DateTimePicker, un formato que coincida con el que se espera la columna de SQL, acá dejo el pedazo de código donde establezco el formato.

```
      dtpFechaNac.MaxDate = DateTime.Today
      dtpFechaNac.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
      dtpFechaNac.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Y esta la parte donde armo la sentencia SQL

```
sql = $"INSERT INTO Clientes (Apellido,Nombre,IdTipoDoc,NDoc,FechaNac,Direccion,IdLocalidad,Cel,Activo) 
        Values ('{txtApellido.Text}','{txtNombre.Text}',{cmbTipoDoc.SelectedValue},{txtNroDoc.Text},
            '{dtpFechaNac.Value}','{txtDireccion.Text}',{cmbLocalidad.SelectedValue},{txtCel.Text},'{chkActivo.Checked}')"
```

El problema esta en que el valor obtenido por "dtpFechaNac.Value" no respeta el formato especificado anteriormente, a continuación adjunto imagen de cual formato toma.

[image: Formato que toma el DTP]

El formato que toma en este caso seria: MM-dd-yyyy, y como se puede ver, no es el formato que yo le asigné con anterioridad.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `CustomFormat` del control `DateTimePicker` sólo sirve para **mostrar** la fecha que tiene como valor con un formato específico, pero el valor de fecha siempre va a ser un valor DateTime que el programa va a tratar siempre con el mismo formato.

Para obtener la fecha del DateTimePicker con el formato que quieres deberías especificar ese formato al obtener el valor de la siguiente forma:

```
dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

La query SQL te quedaqria de la siguiente forma:

```
sql = $"INSERT INTO Clientes (Apellido,Nombre,IdTipoDoc,NDoc,FechaNac,Direccion,IdLocalidad,Cel,Activo) 
        Values ('{txtApellido.Text}','{txtNombre.Text}',{cmbTipoDoc.SelectedValue},{txtNroDoc.Text},
            '{dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}','{txtDireccion.Text}',{cmbLocalidad.SelectedValue},{txtCel.Text},'{chkActivo.Checked}')"
```